# BitcoinJ Request Specific Amount

Tags: java, bitcoinj, bitcoin-testnet

I'm a java developer implementing bitcoinj in an app that I'm currently working on. However, I could not find an option to specify the amount when creating a receive address. Is it possible, and if possible, how can I do it.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do

Comment: I did request for a fresh address, copied it to my android wallet and transferred some coins into it. It worked as i was able to see the deposit in my balance. But what i wanted now is to specify how much coins the payer should pay me alongside the address. Like when the payer paste the address in their android wallet, it should show them the amount I requested,  so they don't have to enter the amount they wanted to send. The amount should already be displayed on their screen. Thanks in advance

Comment: Still unsolved. Someone should please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [BIP21](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0021.mediawiki) and then use can create QR code or a URI. Both sender and receiver needs to be BIP 21 comparable.

And in bitcoinj you can find [BitcoinURI.java](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/0ea885fa101b6a21f47e6e8804d58e71c4c2e9a6/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/uri/BitcoinURI.java)